# Writing to multiple excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, openpyxl

I am using selenium and openpxyl for webscraping data to excel, but am having issues with trying to figure out a way to write data to multiple excel sheets.

Basically, I have the program which loops through yearly data (2005-2015) but can't figure out how to get each year onto a different excel sheet. So as of now I am manually doing year by year and transferring the data to a different excel workbook.

Thanks and if anything else is needed let me know. :)

UPDATE CODE

```
wb = load_workbook('/Users/Caitlyn/Desktop/Program/Planning.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data')
#Writing to the sheet
sheet.cell(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, value=year) 
columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
```

Comment: have you try this ?  from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('file_name.xlsx')
ws4 = wb2["plan1"]

Comment: You really ought to include some code because what you want to do is easy.

Comment: @LuizLai Thanks for that, I will give it a try!

Comment: @CharlieClark I have updated the question to include how I load the workbook and how a portion is stored to the workbook. My mistake for not including this originally.

Comment: The code is incomplete and it looks like you want to be looping. I suggest you redirect the question to the mailing list. PS `wb.get_sheet_by_name()` is deprecated just use `wb['Data']`